# Why can the maximum value of a numpy array not be expressed in that dtype?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am converting a NumPy array from a float dtype to an integer dtype. In the process, I want to cast values above the maximum value allowable by the dtype to that maximum. But for some reason that fails, and the conversion returns the minimum value. Here is code to reproduce (Python3, Numpy 1.22.2), with just `numpy.inf` as an example

```
float_array = numpy.array([[1, +numpy.inf], [2,2]])
dtype = numpy.dtype(numpy.int64)
cut_array = numpy.nan_to_num(float_array, posinf=numpy.iinfo(dtype).max)
int_array = cut_array.astype(dtype)
```

This returns `int_array[0,1]` equals `-9223372036854775808`.
Why is the maximum value (about 9.2e+18) representable actually not usable for dtype int64?

I tested a bit, a slightly smaller value than the max will work, e.g. using `posinf=numpy.iinfo(dtype).max - 600` will lead to a good conversion.

Comment: The maximum `int64` cannot be represented exactly as 64 bit floating point value.  Take a look at the result of `int(float(9223372036854775807))`.

Comment: Right.  A double only has 54 bits of precision, so you can't store a 64-bit value exactly.

Comment: Actually the [significand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand) has *53* bits, only 52 of which are stored explicitly.  That plus 11 bits for the exponent and 1 bit for the sign gives 64 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments by Warren Weckesser and Tim Roberts:
since a double only has [53](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand) bits of precision, it can not represent exactly int64 e.g.
`int(float(9223372036854775807)) = 9223372036854775808`
In this example, the int conversion has rounded the original int value approximated by float, which essentially added +1 to the int, making it overflow.